# Text disappears when typing long commands in zsh on OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, zsh

When I'm typing a command longer than around 20 characters the text disappears and the cursor moves to a different location in the terminal. How do I stop this? I find it difficult to understand what I'm doing when this happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `$PROMPT` may have escape sequences in it that should be wrapped in `%{...%}` to keep them from being counted when `zsh` calculates the length of the displayed prompt.

Comment: Thanks, I had a missing end %}. Adding this looks to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There could be an incorrect TERM type, resulting in incorrect cursor positioning.  For OS X Terminal.app, this term type works well for most curses-based apps:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-color
```

It should also work well in `xterm`.

Answer (score 0):

Does not happen here so I suspect something in your setup probably of zsh.

Have you tried moving all your ~/.zsh* files and start with a blank environment?